# Creating a digital filter with Matlab

Tags: matlab, filter

I'm trying to create a digital filter which amplifies the higher frequencies of an audiofile.

I wanted to start amplifying at 3.185 KHz=fc and stop at 20 KHz=fd for files with a sampling frequency of 44.1 KHz.

Since I have never done anything like this before I started with pen & paper and firstly created a transfer function in the s-plane.

I thought that

```
G=(1+s/fc)/(1+s/fd)
```

should suffice for now. Afterwards I calculated the tustin-approximaton (per hand and via matlab) and with both ways I come to a filter which looks completely wrong in `fvtool`. (something like `num=[5.304 , -4.934]` and `den=[1 , -0.6303]`).

Does anyone know where I made my mistake or how to create a filter which matches my requirements?

Update @Ryan Smith:

```
[y,fs]=audioread('test.wav');
s=tf('s');
G=(1+(s/3185))/(1+(s/20000))
D=c2d(G,1/fs,'tustin');
fvtool([5.304 -4.934],[1 -0.6303]);
```

On the one which I did on paper I used s=2*fs*((z-1)/(z+1))

Comment: Please add your code for how you created the tustin approximation in Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

I think it must be something like:

```
fc = 3185; fd = 20000;
G_sys = tf([1/fc 1], [1/fd 1]);
```

You can see in Matlab that `G_sys` is different to your `G`.

EDIT:

Should it be like followings

```
fvtool([5.304 -4.934],[1 -0.6303])
```

well i think you reversed the order of `num` and `den` ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is the same transferfunction I am using. (if I multiply your filter with 1 in form of 6.37e07/6.37e07 I get to my transferfunction so it shouldn't change anything)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your edit! I tried this one as well. The problem is that even if it looks better the ampliying still starts at 0 Hz and not at 3185 Hz if I use my sampling frequency of 44100 Hz in fvtool). But I updated my main post with the right fvtool, thank you